# Create new record with the self rererenced Foreignkey relation

Tags: python, django, foreign-key-relationship

Below is the my models.py and made a self reference Foreignkey relationship.

```
class emp_details(models.Model):
    emp_id              =   models.AutoField(primary_key = True) 
    emp_first_name      =   models.CharField(max_length = 50,null = False)
    emp_manager_id      =   models.ForeignKey('self')

a1 = emp_details(emp_first_name = "ramesh",emp_manager_id = 2)
a1.save()
```

Here I am trying to create new record. But I got the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "'2'": "emp_details.emp_manager_id" must be a "emp_details" instance.
```

How can I create a new record with the self rererenced Foreignkey relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, `emp_manager_id` is the foreign key field, so you should assign the id to `emp_manager_id_id`.

```
a1 = emp_details(emp_first_name = "ramesh", emp_manager_id_id=2)
```

It would be better to change the field name to `emp_manager`. Note it's recommended to use CamelCase for your model name, so `EmpDetail` is better than `emp_details`. Putting that together, you have:

```
class EmpDetail(models.Model):
    emp_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True) 
    emp_first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50,null = False)
    emp_manager = models.ForeignKey('self')
```

Now that `emp_manager` is the foreign key, you can assign the id to `emp_manager_id`.

```
a1 = EmpDetail(emp_first_name="ramesh", emp_manager_id_id=2)
```

If you want to set `emp_manager` to the object itself, then you need to save the object to the database first, so that it gets a primary key.

```
a1 = EmpDetail(emp_first_name="ramesh")
a1.save()
a1.emp_manager = a1  # You could do 'a1.emp_manager_id = a1.id' instead 
a1.save()
```

For this to work, you'll need to set `null=True` on the foreign key so that you can save the object without setting `emp_manager`.

```
emp_manager = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True)
```

Comment: Its working fine.But i have small doubt.here instead of value 2.How can i get the self Object ID instead of passing as static argument.Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: You need to save the object first before you can access its id. See my updated answer.